# Value of PI in C

Tags: c, pi

How should one define the value of **PI**? What are the effects of using the various PI definitions? Would declaring the variables as a long double suffice for **PI_b**, float for **PI** and **PI_a**? Could there be a change in the results depending on the defination one is using in a program?

*Thank you.*

```
#ifdef M_PI
#define PI M_PI
#else
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288420   
#endif

//OR 

#define PI_a 3.14159265358979323846 

//OR

#define PI_b 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288420  /* 3 more than LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG */
```

Comment: If you want a `long double` then `3.141592653589793238462643383279502884L`. Note the `L` suffix.

Comment: @TomKarzes, that depends on your C implementation.  The language spec does not require `math.h` or any other standard library header to provide a macro or external variable conveying the value of Pi.

Comment: Without additional detailed information on the use case, this is a matter of opinions. As the existing answers already demonstrate.

Comment: I guess it depends on your purpose, @TomKarzes.  I do not take the OP to be asking for a specific digit sequence, since they already *present* the relevant digit sequences.  It seems pretty clear to me that the question is more broadly about how to use the value of Pi in C source code, and especially how to define a macro to represent it.

Comment: @Yunnosch The OP is having difficulty envisioning the consequences of "under-specifying" value of pi as a constant. The existing answers attempt to demonstrate that, for practical purposes, 7-8 digits are _an elegant sufficiency and any more would likely be superfluous..._ Pity that others suggest "accuracy to the 40th decimal point" when the values seen by users will be rounded to 2 or 3 decimals...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yes. that is your opinion, while you noticed that other opinions exist. I think you are supporting my point...

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, that could be true.  But floating point arithmetic is inherently unstable.  Even for identical definitions of PI, things like optimization flags, CPU architecture, etc. can change floating point results.  Many CPUs have internal floating point registers that are larger than 64 bits, and when used for floating point operations, the results can differ from the results one would obtain from a pure 64-bit IEEE implementation.

Comment: Agreed, @TomKarzes, though I think those factors go beyond what the question is asking.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm foggy on the math class (from decades ago) that tried to explain that the true mathematical accuracy of any calculation derives from the accuracy of the **least** accurate value in the calculation... If, for instance, a sensor delivers a 16bit reading (say 0-65535), having an extra 30digits of accuracy of pi is... what's the word??? ah, yes... overkill... (or perhaps "foolish")... Just an opinion...

Comment: People have had conflicting opinions on this whenever I posted a code for review. Some advised me to use around forty decimal points, while others said it's foolish and stupid. Thank you for your answer @Fe2O3.

Comment: Wikipedia "Floating Point Arithmetic": "The result of rounding differs from the true value by about 0.03 parts per million, and matches the decimal representation of π in the first 7 digits." ... That's a single precision float - 7 decimal digits. I think double takes that up to 14 or 16 decimal digits... Sure, "long double" will go higher... But, if you are calculating the sin of an angle, will you, practically speaking, have a value for the angle precise to 10^-16 radians??? I can't think of anyone who would!! Some here think calculating the millionth digit of pi has practical purpose.

Comment: "How many digits" Read this article about Lorenz and the origins of "Chaos Theory"...https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-first-chaos-theorist-was-a-meteorologist-ee37ec466f62 Another DV for my answer today. Seems that there are those who don't really understand math...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should one define the value of **PI**?

It depends on your objectives.

> Could there be a
> change in the results depending on the defination one is using in a
> program?

In general, absolutely.  How likely that is depends on details of your C implementation's floating-point types, the specific forms of the constants you use, the nature and details of the calculation, and how precisely you express the results.

With your specific examples, it's unlikely.  Read on for details.

> What are the effects of using
> the various PI definitions?  Would declaring the variables as a long
> double suffice for **PI_b**, float for **PI** and **PI_a**?

In the first place, there is rarely a good reason to use `float`, other than for minimizing storage size.  Modern CPUs suffer no performance penalty from using `double`s -- in fact, computing with `double`s may be marginally faster than computing with `float`s.

In the second place, the types of variables to which you assign floating constants is not the only relevant consideration.

Since you raise the questions of data type and variation in results and give estimates of Pi to large numbers of decimal digits, I infer that you are looking for the most precise estimates of Pi supported by the various available floating-point data types, and how to use them in your programs.

In that case, it is important to understand that **numeric constants are assigned data types based on their lexical form**, and that determines their precision.  No matter how many digits you provide, a decimal floating-point constant has type `double` if it is without any suffix, type `float` if it is suffixed with `f` or `F`, or type `long double` if it is suffixed with `l` or `L`.  The precision of the result is limited by the data type, no matter how many digits you write.

In particular, your numeric definitions of `PI`, `PI_a`, and `PI_b` macros all expand to floating constants of type `double`.  They all have more than enough significant decimal digits to fully determine all the bits of a `double` of a typical C implementation, and the leading digits are the same, so in such an implementation they all express *the same* `double` value.  You can assign that value to a variable of type `long double`, but that will not automagically convert it to a higher-precision estimate.

If you want a floating constant expressing a higher precision estimate of Pi than a `double` can accommodate then you need to use a `long double` constant.  For example,

```
// Note the 'L' suffix making this a long double constant:
#define PI_l 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288420L
```

Do note, however, that whether `long double` actually does provide more precision than does `double` is implementation dependent, and even among those that do, not all `long double`s you might meet are precise to the 38 decimal digits of your constant.

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI_l 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288420L

int main(void) {
    // The type casts produce effects equivalent to assigning to a
    // variable of the specified type and then reading back its value:
    printf("As float:       %.24f\n", (float) PI_l);
    printf("As double:      %.24f\n", (double) PI_l);
    printf("As long double: %.24Lf\n", PI_l);
}
```

For me, its output is

```
As float:       3.141592741012573242187500
As double:      3.141592653589793115997963
As long double: 3.141592653589793238512809
```

Note well that the three are all different from each other, and that even the `long double` version diverges at the 20<sup>th</sup> digit from the expression of the constant in the source code.

Comment: How many operations would be required before the innate numerical error crept up into significant digits that might 'corrupt' results printed to 1/100th precision?

Comment: Typically lots, @Fe2O3, hence "It depends on your objectives."  On the other hand, possibly as few as one, depending on the inputs.  I have answered the question I take the OP to have asked.  Whether that is a good or appropriate question to ask is a different matter entirely.